# An error is shown when defining a javascript file

Tags: javascript, vscode-extensions, vscode-snippets

I was able to write javascript codes on vscode, but recently when I create a javascript file on vscode, the js icon does not appear next to the file, and I cannot write the codes inside it because it does not read the codes:

[image]

I cleared Extension JavaScript (ES6) code snippets and reinstalled it but the problem is still there then I installed vue but it didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After you opened that file, look in the status bar. Do you see the JavaScript button there? Like this:

[image]

If not there is probably a different language shown. Click on that to get a selection of languages and choose Javascript from that.

Comment: I did this, and the word batch appears to me when I click on it. The JavaScript language does not appear to me, but other languages ​​appear to me

Comment: That sounds as if the Java language server does not start. Check the output channels if you find one that gives you more information in this regard.

Comment: The problem was solved when I clicked on batch. I did not notice that there was a scroll, so I found the language and the problem was solved. Thank you

Comment: OK, glad to hear that. If you found my answer useful then please accept it (via the gray check mark left below the vote buttons on the left). If you think it's worth it you can also upvote it.